# Hotkey for quick switching sculpting brushes

Tags: shortcut

I didn't do sculpting in blender for a while. I remember there's a hotkey to invoke a menu of brush icons under mouse cursor. I can then choose the brush I need without moving my mouse, which is very convenient when sculpting.
It's like a pie menu but it's a list of icons.

However, I forget what is the key and couldn't find any clues on that :(
It's like Ctrl or Shift + some magic key. Does anyone know about it? Thanks

Comment: with Shift Spacebar you can have the Tool bar under your cursor, you'll also see associated shortcuts, is it what you want?

Comment: Oh yes, that's what i want. Thanks moonboots!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, luckily my finger has its memory lol
It's Shift + Space.
[image]

[image]